# Failed request at Google scholar using python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, bibtex, google-scholar

I had a problem while attempting to get text from a url using Python *requests* module.

After managing to find the url of the bibtex of academic articles, I have problems to get the text containing the bibtex.

As an example, through some Python lines of code I obtain this [link](https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar.bib?q=info:46dohauatq8J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&ct=citation&cd=0), which contain the following bibtex:

@article{milgrom1994monotone, title={Monotone comparative statics}, author={Milgrom, Paul and Shannon, Chris}, journal={Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society}, pages={157--180}, year={1994}, publisher={JSTOR}}

It don't manage to extract the text using the code below:

```
`bibtex = requests.get(googlescholar + urlbib).text`
```

where google scholar is a string containing "https://scholar.google.com.br" and url is "/scholar.bib?q=info:46dohauatq8J:scholar.google.com/&output=citation&hl=en&ct=citation&cd=0".

I feel like I'm missing something, because when I copy and paste the full url on the Google Chrome it works normally; i.e., it opens the page instead of issuing an error message.

Comment: what error does it give u?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't issue an error message. It just doesn't get the bibtex. Instead, the text that is obtain is the following:

Comment: Error 403 (Forbidden)!!

That’s an error.
Your client does not have permission to get URL /scholar.bib?q=info:46dohauatq8J:scholar.google.com/&amp;output=citation&amp;hl=en&amp;ct=citation&amp;cd=0 from this server.
Please see Google's Terms of Service posted at http://www.google.com/terms_of_service.html
That’s all we know.

Comment: I am afraid google is blocking your request